# Salesforce two step authentication on external application

Tags: salesforce

I am currently getting an authentication failure when trying to get a token to use for API calls to Salesforce. I believe it has to do with two factor authentication. It makes sense as now I have to approve the login on my phone when logging in through the browser, I just don't know how to do the two factor with authenticating for an API call.

Any advice would be helpful!

Thanks you in advanced.

Comment: why did you tag it with communities, you need community user api access (only way is the real UI login, with 2-factor if enabled). Will your integration be initiated by human that can complete 2FA or are you after completely "silent" backend connection? There's OAuth flow with refresh tokens (human could initiate it once on some admin page, complete 2FA and from that point onwards not needed) or authorisation with JWT (username + certificate + the fact this user is preapproved in SF rather than username + password + 2FA)